# Repetition sign for Norwegian (?) songs

Tags: symbols

The `$\textdiscount$` has only 1 dot on each side of the line. I would rather have two points on each side, as in the link. How may I get it?

[Desired repetition sign](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4s7xdptghqcase/Untitled1.pdf?dl=0):

[image: repetition sign]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\colon$}/\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\colon$}$
\end{document}` ?

Comment: Thanks! That worked with few adjustments. You deserve some points.

Comment: Thanks, I have enough points. ;-) But you might want to post what you have, either as an answer or add it to the question. There might be some experts (e.g. Steven) seeing this provide you with some more insights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach using a stack.  It would help to know the context of it's use.  For example, I have not added any math space around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\repsign{\stackengine{0pt}{:\kern2pt:}{\scalerel*{/}{X}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\repsign
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not knowing its true appearance (I can't access the provided link), here is another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\repsign{\stackengine{0pt}{:\kern2pt:}{%
  \scalerel*{\ooalign{/\cr\kern.4pt/}}{Xg}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\repsign
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, based on a comment from the OP,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\repsign{\stackengine{0pt}{\kern-.7pt\itshape:\kern1pt:\/}{%
  \scalerel*{\ooalign{/\cr\kern.25pt/}}{Xg}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\repsign
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping you'd see this. ;-)

Comment: Nice! Can you tilt the colons so that they are askew as the slash?

Comment: It is for a poem where I use the verse package.

Comment: @Sapiens Please see my edit...

Comment: Great! That is a nice one! :)